# i want to try streaming a twitch live video in android app in java through webView but the stream is mute and not in full screen in landscape mode

Tags: java, android, live-streaming, twitch, twitch-api

> i want to try streaming a twitch live video in android app in java through webView but the stream is mute and not in full screen in landscape mode.

**Twitch live Video Streaming is working fine but i want 2 changes.**

*1. Stream start but on mute, but i have to unmute manually.*
*2. Stream not play in full screen even i add lanscape mode.*

**If you have any idea to solve these problem help me, I will be very grateful to you**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView mWebView;
    TextView textView;
    String url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        url = "https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=jandarpan_news&enableExtensions=true&muted=false&parent=twitch.tv&player=popout&quality=auto&volume=1";

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textV);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
       
        webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36";
        webSettings.setUserAgentString(userAgent);
        mWebView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final android.webkit.PermissionRequest request) {
                request.grant(request.getResources());
            }
        });

        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }

}
```